# JavaFx cannot cast text to textField and cannot cast textField to text?

Tags: java, javafx, casting

I am trying to do an application for my Java class. Mainly we are learning out to use github, but my problem came with JavaFX. I am suppose to create a form on several panes and Scenes, and right at the last one when the user hits submit the TextFields content should be placed inside a file.

My idea to achieve this was to pass the textfields into the last pane has a parameter and create a bufferedwriter once the submit button is pressed, adding all the text into a new file. so the idea was working perfect, I passed a Pane since all the textFields are inside one VBox and when I write them I cast them has textFields, but when I run it tells me that text cannot be cast to textfield, so when I try to cast to text instead, it would tell me the opposite! that textfield cannot be cast to text! I tried the buffer using the textArea inside the code and it worked fine! I don't understand why is not working with the pane im passing

Note: right at the end I tried concatenating to a string see if the buffer was the problem, but it tells me the same error even doing it this way

this is the code:

```
    public class RulesPane extends VBox{
    public RulesPane(Stage mainStage, Scene mainScene, Pane pane) {
        this.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        BackgroundImage background = new BackgroundImage(new Image("water.png",900,600,false,true), 
                BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                  BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
        this.setBackground(new Background(background));

        File logoPath = new File("src/swimclub_Logo.png");
        Image logoImage = new Image(logoPath.toURI().toString());
        ImageView logo = new ImageView(logoImage);

        TextArea agreement = new TextArea();
        agreement.setEditable(false);
        agreement.setPrefHeight(400);
        agreement.setMaxWidth(600);
        agreement.setWrapText(true);
        agreement.setText("This is text");

        CheckBox agree = new CheckBox("I Agree");

        HBox buttons = new HBox();
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(50, 0, 0, 60));
        buttons.setSpacing(300);

        Button back = new Button();
        back.setText("Back");
        back.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            mainStage.setScene(mainScene);
        });

        Button exit = new Button();
        exit.setText("Exit");
        exit.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            Platform.exit();
        });

        Button submit = new Button();
        submit.setText("Submit Form");
        submit.setDisable(true);
        submit.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            File file = new File("user_info.txt");
            try {
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                String contentToSave = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < pane.getChildren().size(); i++) 
                    contentToSave += ( (TextField) pane.getChildren().get(i)).getText();

                out.write(contentToSave);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


        //CheckBox event handler to make the submit button available or unavailable when pressed
        agree.setOnAction(e->{
            if(agree.isSelected()) 
                submit.setDisable(false);
            else
                submit.setDisable(true);
        });

        buttons.getChildren().addAll(back, exit, submit);
        this.getChildren().addAll(logo , agreement, agree, buttons);
        }
}
```

This is where is coming from

```
 public class registration extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane main = new BorderPane();
    VBox questions = new VBox();
    VBox titlePane = new VBox();
    HBox buttonPane = new HBox();


    Text title = new Text("Welcome to the Swimming Club Registration!");


    Text question1 = new Text("How did you hear about our club?");
    Text question2 = new Text("Have you ever been in any clubs for swimming before?");
    Text question3 = new Text("Do you swim competitvly or for fun?");

    TextField question1Answer = new TextField();
    TextField question2Answer = new TextField();
    TextField question3Answer = new TextField();
    question1Answer.setPromptText("Enter where you heard about our club (Internet, Flyer, etc)");
    question2Answer.setPromptText("Enter Yes or No");
    question3Answer.setPromptText("Enter Competitvly or Fun");

    Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
    Button continueButton = new Button("Continue");

    File logoPath = new File("src/swimclub_Logo.png");
    Image logoImage = new Image(logoPath.toURI().toString());
    ImageView logo = new ImageView(logoImage);

    buttonPane.getChildren().addAll(cancelButton, continueButton);
    titlePane.getChildren().addAll(title, logo);
    questions.getChildren().addAll(question1,question1Answer,question2,question2Answer,question3,question3Answer);

    titlePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    buttonPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    titlePane.setPadding(new Insets(10,0,20,0));
    questions.setPadding(new Insets(0,10,0,10));
    buttonPane.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,10,0));

    main.setTop(titlePane);
    main.setCenter(questions);
    main.setBottom(buttonPane);



    Scene scene = new Scene(main, 900, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    /**
     * @josegeorges
     * here I am adding the rules pane with the rules scene and setting up the
     * continueButton to go to it for now
     * I am also saving the textFields into a string and passing the content to the pane
     */
    continueButton.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
    String contentToSave = "";
    contentToSave += question1Answer.getText() + ",";
    contentToSave += question2Answer.getText() + ",";
    contentToSave += question3Answer.getText() + ",";

    RulesPane rulesPane = new RulesPane(primaryStage, scene, contentToSave);
    RulesScene rulesScene = new RulesScene(rulesPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(rulesScene);
    });

}

 }
```

Comment: Let me get this straight: You write a whole TextField into a text file? Well that won´t do the trick. Use the the text of the field only for tasks like that.

Comment: yeah which is way I am using the getText() method, so that I can use the text inside, but it'll throw me the error

Comment: Please a minimal runnable program which we can try our self without missing methods or custom class, not only the above code is incomplete but you have errors like the constructor or RulesPane which you call with arguments ( Stage , Scene , String ) and it's definition is ( Stage, Scene, Pane ), In addition I have no idea what RulesScene is about. Try to make a small example to reproduce your problem and while doing so you will probably find out the wrong casting.

Comment: You say your `TextField`s are in a `VBox` but you have `(TextField)Pane...`?

Comment: Show your `StackTrace` and point out the line of code that's throwing the error.

Comment: That doesn't compile. The `RulesPane` constructor you have shown takes parameters of type `(Stage, Scene, Pane)`, but you are passing a `String` as the third parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't see where the Pane is exactly coming from, I'm gonna assume that when you said you have TextFields in a VBox, that VBox is inside of that pane. If so, the problem looks like you're casting TextFields to Pane, not TextFields to Pane's children, which if it's in a VBox you'd want to get it's (Vbox's) children anyway. So:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < pane.getChildren().size(); i++) {
     Node child1 = group.getChildren().get(i);
     if (child1 instanceof VBox) {
         for(Node child2:((VBox) child1).getChildren()) {
             if (child2 instanceof TextField) {
                 contentToSave += (TextField) child2.getText();
             }
          }
      }
   }
```

Instead of  your for loop in the try-block which tries to make a Pane into a TextField, this would get the children of pane, assuming they're vbox (if they are,) then get the children of VBox and assume they're TextFields if (if they are.)

If that doesn't do it, I'd reccomend posting the rest of your code (where Pane is coming from,) and exactly what error it's throwing.

Comment: what I am passing has Pane would be a VBox. the rest of the code is not needed because I tried doing it inside of the class where the VBox and TextFields where instantiated just for testing purposes and it throws the same error.

Comment: Not saying you should put this in the other part of the code, in order to understand what's going on here (what is inside of the Pane you're trying to use) it'd be helpful to see where it's coming from.

Comment: Okay I added it

Comment: String contentToSave = ""; and new RulesPane(primaryStage, scene, contentToSave);, You're attempting to create RulesPane(Stage, Scene, Pane) with String instead of Pane. Change the constructor to have String or maybe try using a String[] instead, since you're storing multiple strings